# Why would NetBeans not display correctly file names or other text in dialogs?

Tags: netbeans

While trying to make a new project in NetBeans 7.2.1 I've noticed that in the "New Project" dialog, after I select a category (Java, Java FX, Java Web, etc), the project types only show up as icons, the text becoming visible only after I click an icon. 
Any idea of what could have caused this behavior?

I could post an image but I'm a new user and don't have enough points for that yet.

Here's a link, though: http://www.flickr.com/photos/67586865@N08/8436549191/

Later edit: I've noticed this in other dialogs, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the graphical card driver had some problems, and have figured this out after strange behaviors appeared in other applications, too. After re-installing the driver everything went smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I just deactivated some of my plugins including Dark Nimbus Theme, and

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in my case the theme did not seem to have anything to do with the behavior.